# regex python Поиск по вложенным группам

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть следующий текст вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
text = """
\tvoid hello_world (void) :
\t\treturn_type void
\t\twords_in_name 2
\t\t\tfirst, hello
\t\t\tsecond, world
\t\tparam_count 1
\tint main (char argv, char argc) :
\t\treturn_type int
\t\twords_in_name 1
\t\t\tfirst, main
\t\tparam_count 2
"""
```

Я пытаюсь разбить текст на подгруппы при помощи следующего регулярного выражения:

```
for function_match in re.finditer(r'\t{1}.+ :\n(\t{2}.+\n(\t{3}.+, .+\n)*){3}', text):
   print(function_match.group(1))
```

Но из-за того, что я использую квантификаторы, при помощи метода function_match.group(1) могу получить лишь последнее соответствие шаблона. Есть ли способы получить список всех вхождений, чтобы обращаться к ним по индексу?
Или, если перефразировать, есть ли возможность, используя метод .group(N), обратиться к паре 'b2, а не c3':

```
string='a1b2c3'
print(re.search(r'(?P<need_pair>\w\d)+', string).group('need_pair'))) #out: c3
```

p.s. Не хотелось бы отказываться от квантификаторов, так как нужно точное соответствие шаблону.

Comment: Скажите, а почему вы решили приложить пример исходного текста в виде скриншота?

Comment: На превью текст был в одну строку и не видно было уровней табуляции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В рамках стандартного `re` такое невозможно. Группа всегда будет хранить только последнее соответствие. Модуль [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) может выдать всю "историю" соответствий группы, но иерархию вы также не получите (на обычном `re` то же самое делается тремя отдельными регекспами).

Но ничего же не мешает распарсить иерархично хоть теми же регулярными выражениями. Первый регексп берёт строку с одним табом (процедура) и остальные "подстроки" как "тело" этой процедуры. Второй регексп уже работает с "телом процедуры". И т.д.

```
import re

parsed = {}
for m1 in re.finditer(r'^\t{1}(?P<proc>[^\t].*?)\s+:\s*\n(?P<body>(^\t{2}[^\t].*?\n(^\t{3}[^\t].*?\n)*)+)', text, flags=re.M):
    parsed[m1["proc"]] = {}
    print(f'Procedure: {m1["proc"]}')
    for m2 in re.finditer(r'^\t{2}(?P<prop_name>[^\t].*?)\s+(?P<prop_value>.+?)\n(?P<options>(^\t{3}[^\t].*?\n)*)', m1["body"], flags=re.M):
        parsed[m1["proc"]][m2["prop_name"]] = {"value": m2["prop_value"], "options": {}}
        print(f'   Property `{m2["prop_name"]}` = `{m2["prop_value"]}`')
        for m3 in re.finditer(r'^\t{3}(?P<name>[^\t].*?),\s+(?P<value>.+?)$', m2["options"], flags=re.M):
            parsed[m1["proc"]][m2["prop_name"]]["options"][m3["name"]] = m3["value"]
            print(f'      Option `{m3["name"]}` : `{m3["value"]}`')
        if not parsed[m1["proc"]][m2["prop_name"]]["options"]: 
            del parsed[m1["proc"]][m2["prop_name"]]["options"]

print("-"*40)
from pprint import pprint
pprint(parsed)
```

В результате имеем:

```
Procedure: void hello_world (void)
   Property `return_type` = `void`
   Property `words_in_name` = `2`
      Option `first` : `hello`
      Option `second` : `world`
   Property `param_count` = `1`
Procedure: int main (char argv, char argc)
   Property `return_type` = `int`
   Property `words_in_name` = `1`
      Option `first` : `main`
   Property `param_count` = `2`
----------------------------------------
{'int main (char argv, char argc)': {'param_count': {'value': '2'},
                                     'return_type': {'value': 'int'},
                                     'words_in_name': {'options': {'first': 'main'},
                                                       'value': '1'}},
 'void hello_world (void)': {'param_count': {'value': '1'},
                             'return_type': {'value': 'void'},
                             'words_in_name': {'options': {'first': 'hello',
                                                           'second': 'world'},
                                               'value': '2'}}}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!